# Take sb on as a job

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I liked to undestand the sentence below but it didn't seem to be right.

> He took a few aspiring actors as their manager and agent.

It should mean **He** is **their manger and agent**. But as in the sentence, grammatically, it sounds like the actors would work as their manager and agent.

How do native English people understand the difference?

Comment: You use _take on_ in the title but only _took_ in your example! 'A few' actors cannot be 'their manager' in the singular, so it should be clear from the context that 'he' is the manager.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself about the meaning and usage of "take someone on"? [How to ask a good question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)